# Export parameters values in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, closures

using mongojs to access a mongodb database, the following lines retrieve users:

```
db.users.find({}, function(err, some_users) {});
```

Users found are stored in some_users parameter.

Then, I would like to use some_users after the `db.users.find()` call, not only in the anoymous function.

I've tried to play with closures, but without success.

Any idea?

Comment: Assuming the DB access is asynchronous you have to deal with the response within the callback function (or in other functions that you call from the callback), though within the callback you can store a reference to the results in a global variable and then use that later in response to other events. You just can't use it immediately after the `.find()` call because, again, the call is (I'm assuming) async.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have access to `some_users` after the call to `find`, then you should initialize a variable to hold the result outside of the anonymous function's scope. e.g.

```
var someUsers;
db.users.find({}, function(err, some_users) {someUsers = some_users});
//Do things with the filled in someUsers
```

As noted by nnnnnn in the comments, presuming `find` is an asynchronous call, `someUsers` will not be immediately filled in after the call to `find`.